# Stress Testing / Load Testing Proxy services / web servers

Tags: apache-2.2, load-testing, stress-testing

What are the best load testing tools for stress testing web servers and proxy services such as NAT.

**Some metrics to consider include**

- throughput.
- hits per second.
- machine load.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the basic load testing tools are

httperf
http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/

apache bench
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

siege
http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home

jmeter - has dynamic page features.
http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/

Comment: are these not all for http services though. what about NAT.

Comment: Do you mean NAT as in "Network Address Translation"?  If yes, I don't think you will find any testing tools for that. It isn't really a proxy service or a protocol. It is a technique used by routers.  You would load test it the same way you would load test any other router - by pushing lots of traffic through it.  In your case, that would apparently be HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned machine load data as a priority, I'll point out that most of the previously mentioned tools do not included any provision for monitoring your server or integrating data from the servers into the results. You'll probably want to consider a more sophisticated tool, such as our [Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/) product or one of its competitors.